# Google Play Service SDK 6.5でのLocationClientの代わりの実装は？

Tags: android, google-play-service

Google Play Service SDKを6.5にアップデートしたらLocationClientが使えなくなりました。代わりの実装はどうすれば良いのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

LocationClientは廃止され、代わりにGoogleApiClientを使うことになりました。

```
public class MyActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,                   
                                   GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
  private GoogleApiClient locationClient;

  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    locationClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(ctx)
      .addApi(LocationServices.API)
      .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
      .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
      .build();
    locationClient.connect();
  }

  // 最新の現在地を取得
  public Location getLastLocation() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(locationClient);
  }
}
```

上記は簡略化したコード例です。

それと`build.gradle`には下記のように指定します。

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:6.5.+'
```