# Google Play Service SDKバージョンについて

Tags: google-play-service

Google Play Service SDKが6.5になってからLocationClientが使えなくなったとのことですが、Google Play Service SDKのバージョンを下げたりすることは可能でしょうか？

**追記**
確かにバージョンを下げるのは推奨はされないと思いますし、長期的に使用するつもりはありません。
ただすぐに動作の確認に使用したいので方法があれば教えていただきたいです。

**追記2**
分かりました。ご回答ありがとうございました。

**追記3**
fkmさん、＄ANDROID_HOME～というのはAndroid Studioのフォルダの中にあるのでしょうか？
AMDROID_HOMEというのが見つからないです。
初心者なものであまり詳しくないので教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下げる方法はあるかという答えに対しては「ない」となります。

ただしもう配布されていない古いバージョンのSDKを何らかの手段で手に入れて、使い続けることはできます。しかし、そうすべきではないですし、意味もありません。

なぜなら、`Google Play Service`のライブラリとは、端末にインストールされている「Google Play 開発者サービス」というAPKの機能を呼び出すためのインターフェースだからです。

このため、SDK側のバージョンを落としたとしても、実際の端末側の「Google Play 開発者サービス」のバージョンが自動的に更新されるため、互換性が維持されません。

[Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)の廃止されたインターフェースの説明にも、

> If you used those APIs in your app and want to call Google Play services 6.5 or higher APIs, you must switch to the new programming model that utilizes GoogleApiClient.

`GoogleApiClient`を利用した新しいAPIに切り替えなければならない（must）と記述されていますので、新しいAPIを利用された方がいいと思います。

具体的なコードについては、過去に「[Google Play Service SDK 6.5でのLocationClientの代わりの実装は？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1748/google-play-service-sdk-6-5%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AElocationclient%E3%81%AE%E4%BB%A3%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8A%E3%81%AE%E5%AE%9F%E8%A3%85%E3%81%AF)」という質問がありましたので、そちらが参考になると思います。

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio(gradle)を使用しており、`$ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services/`
の中に`6.1.71`のような旧バージョンが残っていれば、`build.gradle`で次のようにバージョン指定すれば一応使えます。

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
}
```